# Alogrithm for balancing the load in multiple worker threads

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a HashMap with key1 to keyn, and the value for each key is a list of objects with varying number of objects on each.

I also know the total number of objects (which is distributed among various keys).

My objective is to load the data into ***T*** threads, with ***K*** as the average number of records in each thread.

> ***Constraint***:
>   The list of objects for a single key should go to single thread. (or cannot be splitted).
>   However, we can group different list of records with different keys.

Is there any proven algorithm which is doing the same task?

Example:

> Total size is = 1000 
>   Request Map =
>
> > k1  ->  100 
> >     k2  ->  50  
> >     k3  ->  200 
> >     k4  ->  250 
> >     k5  ->  150 
> >     k6  ->  80 
> >     k7  ->  60 
> >     k8  ->  90 
> >     k9  ->  20

Now the output can be:

> > T1 = k4                (250)
> >     T2 = k3 + k2           (250)
> >     T3 = k1 + k5           (250)
> >     T4 = k6 + k7 + k8 + k9 (250)

Comment: Or do what scheduling systems frequently do: sort the chunks by size, send the largest to thread 1, the next largest to thread 2, etc.  When thread N finishes it gets the next chunk (the largest remaining), etc.  Not guaranteed to  be optimal, often good enough and often, if workload is impractical to estimate accurately, better than that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, unfortunately I need to provide the number of total threads required prior to the initiation of threads. 
My logic over here is, to sort the key-size map (as you told) then to take the largest out of it as the _**K**_. Then to search for the suitable match in the rest of the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as the [Bin Packing Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) where `V = total-size/thread-count`